# Redux-saga : can't access class instance inside saga?

Tags: dependency-injection, redux-saga

I am trying to inject dependencies into the top rootSaga. Seems like whenever i try to access a property of an instance, it is undefined and it can't access `this.myClassProp`

Why are those instance not accessible through saga ?

#### Declare dependency :

```
export const dependencies: Dependencies = {
    imageFetchingGateway: new HttpImageFetchingGateway()
}
```

```
export const configureStore = () => createReduxStore(dependencies)
```

#### Dependency implementation (faked)

```
export class HttpImageFetchingGateway implements ImageFetcherGateway {

    private readonly pictureName: string;

    constructor() {
        this.pictureName = "fakeHttpIamge"
    }

    * fetch() {
        yield delay(1000);
        //yield put(image_fetched("someString"));     --> This will work and dispatch the correct payload
        yield put(image_fetched(this.pictureName));   --> This will fail
    }
}
```

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'pictureName' of null**

#### Create store, DI and run Saga

```
export function createReduxStore(dependencies: Dependencies): Store<AppState> {
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
    let store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));
    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga, dependencies);
    return store;
}
```

#### RootSaga

```
export default function* rootSaga(dependencies: Dependencies) {
    yield takeEvery(fetch, dependencies.imageFetchingGateway.fetch)
}
```

#### Summary

I can access `dependencies.imageFetchingGateway.fetch` and disptach actions and run effects inside the generator. However every attritube that is owned by the instance `new HttpImageFetchingGateway()` and accessible with `this` tells me this instance is undefined.

The construtor sets `pictureName` properly

I also added DI tag since the final goal here is to be able to tweak the dependencies on which saga will run

Answer (score 0):

generators cant be instatiated, and there for have no knowledge of `this`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DrogoNevets.
That means you can't have sagas inside classes ?
Also, is this how you would DI with Saga ? (without the generator in the class though)

Comment: when you create the generator. you can pass in an argument at that point.

Comment: actually i changed ```* fetch() {}``` to  ```fetch() {}``` (and remove all effects from Saga) inside ```HttpImageFetchingGateway``` and the result is the same...